# Do I need to opt-in to Ivy to use dynamic imports when lazy loading routes (Angular 8)?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

I've recently upgraded to Angular 8 and want to make use of the new dynamic imports feature.

I want to convert this:

```
 { path: 'payments', loadChildren: './components/payments/payments.module#PaymentsModule' }
```

To this:

```
 { path: 'payments', loadChildren: () => import('./components/payments/payments.module').then(m => m.PaymentsModule)}
```

However my code editor (VSCode) throws a `Dynamic import is only supported when '--module' flag is 'commonjs' or 'esNext'` error, which I'm unsure how to fix.

On the Angular update guide ([https://update.angular.io/](https://blog.angularindepth.com/automatically-upgrade-lazy-loaded-angular-modules-for-ivy-e760872e6084)), when talking about using the new `import` syntax, it says:

> For lazy loaded modules via the router, importing via string is
>   deprecated. ng update will take care of this automatically. The new
>   syntax leverages the ecosystem wide support for import rather than our
>   custom rewrites.

`ng update` did not do this automatically and throws the aforementioned error when manually changing the syntax.

I read an [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/automatically-upgrade-lazy-loaded-angular-modules-for-ivy-e760872e6084) by one of the maintainers of this new feature and he mentions that I will need to opt-in to Ivy.

I'm not sure if this is an Angular 8 bug, or if I will need to opt-in to Ivy (in which case, the docs need to be clearer)

My package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.800.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.0.0",
    "basic-keyboard-event-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.3",
    "ngx-logger": "^3.3.11",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/karma-viewport": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/node": "12.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~5.0.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gzipper": "^2.5.1",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-viewport": "^1.0.4",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.35.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2"
   }
```

Comment: I just updated using ```ng update``` and this was taken care of for me without opting in to Ivy

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Ivy to use this new feature. But you have to change your `tsconfig.json`, and have the following line:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

I had `es2015` as the value before. Changing to `commonjs` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Like [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11487196/tony-ngo) said in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375703/angular-8-lazy-loading-modules-error-ts1323-dynamic-import-is-only-supporte), you need to add `"module": "esnext"` to the tsconfig.json file. Also make sure you change the same line in the tsconfig.app.json if you have a different value there.

After that I got no error in the VSCode, but got another error when compilating, but I think is a different issue (`Module parse failed: Unexpected token`) and this may solve it for you.