# Angular 8 - Lazy loading modules : Error TS1323: Dynamic import is only supported when '--module' flag is 'commonjs' or 'esNext'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, angular8

When I updated Angular from 7 to Angular 8, getting error for lazy loading modules

I have tried the options, which are there in the angular upgradation guide

Made the below changes:

**Before**

```
    loadChildren: '../feature/path/sample- 
                         tage.module#SameTagModule'
```

**After**

```
   loadChildren: () => import('../feature/path/sample- 
                      tags.module').then(m => m.CreateLinksModule)
```

> error TS1323: Dynamic import is only supported when '--module' flag is
>   'commonjs' or 'esNext'.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You are using dynamic import so you have to change your tsconfig.json like this to target your code to `esnext` module

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext", // add this line
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Also make sure to check tsconfig.app.json dont have module and target config something like this

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `ng new` doesn't use this by default.  Is there a reason?

Comment: It seems to work in Edge, Chrome, Firefox and IE11 when I uncomment the IE11 section in polyfills so I'm happy.

Comment: I had to remove the `"module": "es2015"` line from my `tsconfig.app.json` file

Comment: @ranbuch, I had the same problem but did not remove the line, I just changed it to `"module": "esnext"` as well.

Comment: still facing the same problem event after updating tsconfig.json file

Comment: did you already restart your server ? also check your tsconfig.app.json too

Comment: The target is still `es2015` ?

Comment: You can target es2015 for modern browser

Comment: for me it was `tsconfig-aot.json`. I have changed it to `esnext` from `es2015`

Comment: Note that what I believe Tony (OP) meant in his second paragraph was "Make sure that you don't also have a `tsconfig.app.json` file with a second `module` declaration that's overriding your main `tsconfig.json`. I was confused until I found this guide, which essentially said the same thing but made more sense: https://icetutor.com/question/angular-8-lazy-loading-modules-error-ts1323-dynamic-import-is-only-supported-when-module-flag-is-commonjs-or-esnext/

Comment: One thing to note, your intelliense using VS code can get stuck after making this change, so I had to restart my machine and it was fine then.

Answer (score 48):

Just want to add my experience to @Tony's answer.
After changing `tsconfig.json` it still showed an error (red underline). **Only after reopening the editor** (I used VSCode) did I see the red underline disappear.

Comment: I dont have tsconfig.app.json file. Should I create one?

Comment: Yes, please refer this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916989/how-can-i-generate-tsconfig-json-file

Comment: In IDEA Intelij I had the same issue. You need to reopen the project.

Comment: Yeah. You saved my day.

Comment: Thanks. I had this too.

Answer (score 37):

Just adding to @Tony's anwser, you might also need to do the same (change to "module": "esnext" ) in the tsconfig.app.json. In my case the tsconfig.json was already using esnext as the module but the tsconfig.app.json was still using es2015 and that caused this error.

Comment: We can avoid adding "module": "esnext" in the both the files, we can put it in tsconfig.json but not in tsconfig.app.json, as this is already extending the tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 28):

I think the proper way to do this is to adjust `tsconfig.app.json` rather than `tsconfig.json`.

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.app.json` is the Typescript configuration file specific to the *app* that sits beneath the root of the Angular *workspace*.  The `tsconfig.app.json` exists so that if you are building an Angular workspace that has *multiple* apps in it, you can adjust the Typescript configuration separately for each app without having to write redundant configuration properties that overlap between the apps (hence the `extends` property).

Technically, you don't need `tsconfig.app.json` at all.  If you delete it, you will have to place the `"module": "esnext"` in `tsconfig.json`.  If you keep it there, it will take precedence over `tsconfig.json`, so you only need to add the `"module":"esnext"` line in `tsconfig.app.json`.

Comment: Yes, I had to add module: 'esnext' in both tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json

Comment: I agree to @Zach's answer. Always use the most specific Typescript configuration file, unless of course they all share the same configuration, but that's most likely not the case.

Answer (score 5):

Just update the angular version by giving below command. The errors will disappear.

`ng update @angular/core @angular/cli --next`

After that, change the target and module in tsconfig.json file

```
"target": "esnext",
"module": "esnext",
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Worked for me. all routes are working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue only by adding
"include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
in my tsconfig.app.json file.

Answer (score 1):

i resolve this error by by doing following steps
step 1:
"module": "es2015" to 
"module": "AMD" in tsconfig.json

step 2: 
create a new file tsconfig.app.json in app root directory, copy code of Tony Ngo and paste into, then this problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My angular version is 8.2 and I fixed it by just changing "module": "es2015" to "module": "es2020"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ionic framework and VSCode you need to update your Typescript IDE version (> 4)!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with angular 13, I noticed that some services had this issue while others didn't, the difference was

```
@import { Injectable } from '@angular/core/';
```

while this perfectly compiled without no issues on angular 9 but the fix was to remove the / at the end to become'

```
@import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a similar issue migrating to Angular 14 from Angular 7. To fix it, I had to change all "module" and "target" properties in project to "es2020" in the next files:

- tsconfig.json
- tsconfig.app.json